# Exclude Test files from final build of android app

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am a newbie to android. I am using Robolectric to write unit tests for my android app. I am struggling to exclude the Test folder that I have created in the actual application from being included in the final apk or before releasing it to playstore. I have looked in Robolectric documents but I didn't come across any step that speaks about this. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you building your apk?

Comment: I am using option available within Eclipse. Android Tool->Export Signed Application package.

Comment: Try prefixing the test folder with an underscore, e.g., `_tests`

Comment: @shoerat I have created a separate folder by name 'test'. If the project consists of a folder by name 'test' then those folders will not be pulled while generating apk? Sorry if I am sounding stupid but as I mentioned this is my first experience with Android. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: You said _I am struggling to exclude the Test folder_ - what's the name of that "Test folder"? If that is `test`, rename it to `_test`.

Comment: @shoerat The name of test folder is 'Test'. so if its renamed to _test then it will be excluded from apk?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @shoerat Thank you.Appreciate your help.