# Android JUnit testing with files

Tags: android, junit

I have a lot of files required for my JUnit testing that I don't want to include in the app when it is downloaded (a lot of them are bitmaps that would take up space).  Currently all files are stored in the assets folder.  Is there a directory I can put the files in that won't be included when the app is downloaded?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617827/gradle-1-2-exclude-directory-under-resources-sourcesets

Comment: Related: [Exclude Test files from final build of android app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23049782)

Comment: Show us your current directory structure and how you are using them in tests (some code).

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation.

Create a new java library and place all the files you need in your tests under `src/main/resources`. Don't use `src/test/resources` or you won't have visibility of the files.

Then simply import the module as part of your test dependencies.

```
testCompile project(':files-module') // for java modules
```

or

```
androidTestCompile project(':files-module') // for android modules
```

You should then be able to gain access to the files through `getResourceAsStream("/" + filename)`

Because the module is only used as a dependency in tests nothing will be included in your production code.